Skolem functions in COQ
I am new to COQ. Is there a way to prove each predicate has a Skolem function?
For all formulas $\phi$,
$$\forall x\exists y:\phi(x,y) \Rightarrow \exists F\forall x: \phi(x,F x).$$
The COQ formatting of the theorem for predicates on natural numbers is
Theorem Skolem : forall p:nat -> nat -> Prop, (forall x:nat, exists y:nat, p x y) -> (exists f:nat->nat, forall x:nat, p x (f x)).

Be aware that there are two kinds of existence in Coq, one in Prop and one in Type, written respectively exists x, P x and {x | P x}. The former, which you wrote, only validates a very weak form of unique choice due to the so-called singleton elimination criterion. The latter satisfies unrestricted choice. Which one you want to really use depends on the context.

@Pierre-MariePédrot Is it possible to elaborate or provide sources what this is about?

@Pierre-MariePédrot New question relating to this https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/4331/axiom-of-countable-choice-in-coq

One can prove dec_finds_result_if_exists : forall P : nat -> Prop, (forall n, {P n} + {~ P n}) -> (exists n, P n) -> { n : nat | P n } without any axioms: Link
For p : nat -> nat -> Prop, if you can show p_DEC : forall x, forall y, {p x y} + {~ p x y}, then you have forall x, ((exists y, p x y) -> { y : nat | p x y }) by using dec_finds_result_if_exists, which derives forall x, { y : nat | p x y }.
On the other hand, one can prove (forall x, { y : nat | p x y }) -> { f : nat -> nat | forall x, p x (f x) } without any axioms.
So, one can obtain { f : nat -> nat | forall x, p x (f x) } and exists f, forall x, p x (f x).
If you cannot show p_DEC then I suggest you assume the axiom choice : forall (A B : Type) (R : A -> B -> Prop), (forall x : A, exists y : B, R x y) -> exists f : A -> B, forall x : A, R x (f x) in the module Coq.Logic.ClassicalChoice.

Can you explain how dec_finds_result_if_exists works? I'm surprised you don't need unique choice for this. How do you use the Prop that such an n exists to bound a search that returns something in Type?

@NaïmFavier Exploit Coq.Init.Wf.Acc! Acc has its eliminator Acc_rect, which returns something in Type. Reference: https://plv.mpi-sws.org/coqdoc/stdpp/stdpp.countable.html#choice

In the notation of Coq.Logic.ChoiceFacts, this is FunctionalCountableChoice_on nat, which is not provable in general. A minimal set of assumptions for this to be provable would be that p is a decidable relation and unique choice holds: see classical_denumerable_description_imp_fun_choice.
