Axiom of Choice in COQ
After reading Bauer's excellent answer on how axiom of choice is treated in different varieties of constructive mathematics, a question remains what is the philosophy behind the axiom in COQ. The axiom of choice can be formulated as, for every proposition $\phi$
$$\forall x:A,\exists y:B,\phi(x,y) \Rightarrow \exists F:A\rightarrow B, \forall x:A,  \phi(x,F x).$$
The converse direction of course holds and is not controversial.
According to Bauer Martin-Löf type theory admits the axiom fully. COQ departs from the theory, but what for?
There are immediately apparent possible issues with adopting the axiom. For one, any proposition starting with $\forall x\exists y$ now postulates the existence of a function, and more importantly $\neg \forall x \exists y$ is equivalent with a constructive function not existing, which departs from the traditional reading greatly.

Why are you saying countable choice, but your formulas do not indicate that $x$ ranges over $\mathbb{N}$?

Sorry, fixed now.

It seems like your question is about the axiom of choice in general, and not about the countable choice of which you speak.
Martin-Löf type theory admits choice only when we interpret $\exists$ as $\Sigma$ (and $\forall$ as $\Pi$):
$$(\Pi (x : A) .\, \Sigma (y : B) .\, \phi(x,y)) \to \Sigma (f : A \to B).\, \Pi (x : A) .\,\phi(x, f x)$$
However, in Coq $\exists$ is not $\Sigma$ because Coq has a separate universe of propositions $\mathsf{Prop}$ which behaves differently from $\mathsf{Type}$. One consequence of this difference is that the axiom of choice stated with $\exists$ is not valid in Coq.
So it depends how you formulate the axiom of choice.

Thank you! I was able to find a more extensive discussion of the AOC relating to COQ from years ago, with some more in depth answers by you and others. https://coq-club.inria.narkive.com/zfXJIT7X/axiom-of-choice#

It seems that Prop behaves like propositional truncation presented in HOTT book, and therefore since the proof objects are not accessible the AOC is not provable. Then also decidability guarantees that the axiom holds. Is this a proper way to think about this?

Prop is somewhat weaker than HoTT propositional truncation, because the latter enjoys unique choice by construction, i.e. ||A|| → A whenever A is hProp. It's also a bit stronger because equality can be eliminated from Prop to Type, which is inconsistent with univalence. The keyword here is the singleton elimination criterion.
